# Gluon Mobile SQLDroid No suitable driver found

Tags: gluon, sqldroid

We are evaluating Gluon Mobile, our application will sometimes work offline, so we need to store data in SQLite. Unfortunately we were unable to connect. We follow the gluon-SQLite examples. We create a new Gluon project using maven, add the following to the pom.xml:

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.sqldroid</groupId>
>         <artifactId>sqldroid</artifactId>
>         <version>1.1.0-rc1</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Then in the BasicView class it looks like this:

```
public class BasicView extends View {

private final static String DB_NAME = "sample.db";
private Connection connection = null;

public BasicView() {
    
    Button button = new Button("Create DB!");
    button.setGraphic(new Icon(MaterialDesignIcon.DATA_USAGE));
    button.setOnAction(e -> creatBD());
    
    VBox controls = new VBox(15.0, button);
    controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    
    setCenter(controls);
}

@Override
protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
    appBar.setTitleText("Basic View");
}

private void creatBD() {
    File dir = null;
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:sqldroid:";

    try {
        dir = Services.get(StorageService.class)
                .map(s -> s.getPrivateStorage().get())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IOException("Error: PrivateStorage not available"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String dbPath = dir.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, dir.getAbsolutePath().length() - 6);

    dir = new File(dbPath + "database");

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }

    File db = new File (dir, DB_NAME);
    dbUrl = dbUrl + db.getAbsolutePath();

    Class c = null;

    try {
        c = Class.forName("org.sqldroid.SQLDroidDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And the following error occurs:

```
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103): java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqldroid:/data/user/0/com.gluonapplication.gluonsingleviewproject/database/sample.db
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.gluonapplication.BasicView.creatBD(BasicView.java:76)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.gluonapplication.BasicView.lambda$new$0(BasicView.java:29)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8797)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:107)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonocleView.notifyMouse(MonocleView.java:116)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.notifyMouse(MouseInput.java:328)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.lambda$postMouseEvent$3(MouseInput.java:241)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:597)
[Wed Feb 16 16:37:18 ECT 2022][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled( 2103):      at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:194)
```

Operating System: Fedora 34
JDK: 11
GraalVM: graalvm-svm-java11-linux-gluon-22.0.0.3-Final
JavaFX: javafx-sdk-17.0.2
IDE: IntelliJ 2021.3.2
Android Version: 10

Is there a way to use SQLite or an alternative to SQLite?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because sqldroid cannot load the native Android version of SQLite. Depending on what exactly you want to achieve you could try https://sqljet.com/ which is pure Java and does not have this problem. But it is also no real dabase. If you do not specifically need SQLite then a pure Java dabase like H2 may also be a solution for you.

Comment: hello, we tried H2 but it had problems. SQLJet works fine but does not support SQL queries. For desktop we are going to go with SQLite and for Android SQLJet. Thank you